# OkHttp android 5 crash adcolony and helpshift

Tags: okhttp, adcolony, helpshift

on android 5 only, some 3rd party sdks (adcolony and helpshift) crashes randomly (most of the time when app just started). On android 5 below, both works fine.

Both of them crashes on

> com.android.okhttp.internal.http.JavaApiConverter.extractStatusLine(JavaApiConverter.java:329)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.JavaApiConverter.extractStatusLine(JavaApiConverter.java:324)

Helpshift crash stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.JavaApiConverter.extractStatusLine(JavaApiConverter.java:329)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.JavaApiConverter.extractStatusLine(JavaApiConverter.java:324)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.JavaApiConverter.createOkResponse(JavaApiConverter.java:116)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.ResponseCacheAdapter.get(ResponseCacheAdapter.java:53)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:190)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>   com.helpshift.support.HSApiClient$1.run(HSApiClient.java:318)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Ad colony crash stack trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.JavaApiConverter.extractStatusLine(JavaApiConverter.java:329)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.JavaApiConverter.extractStatusLine(JavaApiConverter.java:324)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.JavaApiConverter.createOkResponse(JavaApiConverter.java:116)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.ResponseCacheAdapter.get(ResponseCacheAdapter.java:53)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:269)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
>   com.jirbo.adcolony.ADCDownload.run(SourceFile:107)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NPE you mentioned seems to be a similar one reported at
okhttp issue thread for android 5.0: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160522

**Probable reason for this Issue :**
You might be using a custom ResponseCache/third party ResponseCache and it is not implemented properly, and okhttp not handling null responses correctly.

**1. If you don't need Response caching**

The quick fix for this NPE is   - Disabling cache on the connection by
`conn.setUseCaches(false)`

**2. In case you need Response caching**

What implementation of ResponseCache you're using? Is it the Android one from android.net.http.HttpResponseCache, or a third-party one?

*Root cause for custom ResponseCache issue*

> The root cause is that Android assumes that the status line (e.g. the
> part of the response that indicates the response code, a message) is
> held as the header with a null key.      This is alluded to in the API
> docs when you look at the header with the index of zero, but is not
> explicit in the methods that return the Map, or that take a String
>
> See here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CacheResponse.html#getHeaders()

From the stacktrace you provided it looks like the issue is related to using custom ResponseCache.
If so, you can disable cache if not needed else you can contact the  maintainers of custom response cache as mentioned in the response for okhttp issue given above.

For any other Helpshift related queries, feel free to contact us at support@helpshift.com